# In jQuery how do I make multiple changes to css in a function?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there an easy way to make multiple changes to the css in jQuery without the extra lines of code? i.e. I have a function:

```
$(function() {
       $('h1[id=300]').click(function(){
       $('#box').css('background','orange');    
       $('#box').animate({
       "left" : "300px"
    }); 
  });           
});
```

Let's say I want to change the div box size. How would I add it within the changes that are already being applied to background color above?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a object where you define the styles as argument for css() , e.g.:

```
 $('#box').css({'background':'orange',
                'width':'200px',
                 height:'100px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
        $("#box").css({
            background:'orange',
            left:'300'
        });
```

(where background and left are your styles)